# ASP.net hide datetime from vb gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

mind my english, I'm loading some data from database and bind into asp gridview as below.

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="last_modified_date">
    <ItemTemplate>                           
        <asp:Label ID="lblModyDate" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase" Text='<%# Bind("last_modified_date") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

but in my db I have datetime column with this value **1900-01-01 00:00:00.000**, which mean this date is not been set, so what I want is if this date found, do not display it in the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `Label` control inside gridview's `ItemTemplate`, you can do `FindControl` to check label value inside `RowDataBound` event like in example below:

```
Protected Sub GridViewID_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewID.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
       Dim lblModyDate As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblModyDate"), Label)

       ' #1900-01-01 00:00:00.000# is just an example format
       ' change this depending on actual datetime representation
       If (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "last_modified_date").ToString().Contains("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000")) Then
           ' hide corresponding value
           lblModyDate.Text = ""
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Or without using any code-behind events, this time using `Eval()` instead of `Bind()`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="last_modified_date">
    <ItemTemplate>                           
        <asp:Label ID="lblModyDate" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase" 
                   Text='<%# If(Convert.ToString(Eval("last_modified_date"), "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}") = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000", "", Eval("last_modified_date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Note:** `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` is a standard representation for `datetime` column, if you're using different string representation in markup page then both date format & value to check with should be adjusted, e.g. `01/01/1900` with `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Related issues:

[Need to check whether date contains 1/1/1900](https://forums.asp.net/t/1647480.aspx?Need%20to%20check%20whether%20date%20contains%201%201%201900)

[Hide 1900-01-01 date in GridView](https://forums.asp.net/t/1095659.aspx?Hide%201900%2001%2001%20date%20in%20GridView)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following condition in your code on gridview load event.

```
if(labelmodydate.text == 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000)
{
labelmodydate.visible = false;
}
```